# sqlite query with strftime always returns None

Tags: python, sqlite, strftime

I have the following function:

```
for i in range(1,13):
        q_totes_1="""SELECT sum(kaxia) FROM es_data WHERE strftime('%%m',es_date)='%s' AND es_orig=1"""%(str(i))
        self.cur.execute(q_totes_1)
        m_totes_1=self.cur.fetchone()[0]
        print q_totes_1
        if m_totes_1 is None:
            m_totes_1=0.0
```

It always returns None while I know that I should have another result. From the `print q_totes_1` I get the query which I execute straightly on sqlite and I get the desired result. All the imports are correct as I already have used them successfully in other functions of the same class.

I tried running a similar query without the `strftime('%%m',es_date)='%s'` portion and it run correctly.

Can somebody give me a hint of what I'm missing?

Comment: what you mean by *It always returns None* ? are you defined this code as a function ?

Comment: @Kasra `m_totes_1` is None; I tried with `self.cur.fetchall()` also and got `(None,)`

Comment: @Filippos Use a single % and check

Comment: @ Bhargav Rao I get `ValueError: unsupported format character 'm' (0x6d) at index 48`

Comment: @Filippos Final `"""SELECT sum(kaxia) FROM es_data WHERE strftime('%%m',es_date)= ? AND es_orig=1""",(str(i),) `

Comment: @Bhargav Rao Almost there? Got a `operation parameter must be str or unicode` Same result with %% and %.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I got the query to execute and to my disappointment it was annoyingly simple:

The query should have this format (I tend to ignore the possibility of injections as the only interaction with the DB will be through the python app):

```
SELECT sum(kaxia) FROM es_data WHERE strftime('%%m',es_date,'unixepoch')= '%s'AND es_orig=1"""%(str(i))
```

The lack of the `'unixepoch'` modifier seemed to output a `None` value result.

Many thanks to all who tried to help...

Comment: Great. Accept your answer as correct and mark this question as answered

Answer (score 1):

Change it to

```
self.cur.execute( """SELECT sum(kaxia) FROM es_data WHERE strftime('%m',es_date)= ? AND es_orig=1""",(str(i),) )
```

Your code will be

```
for i in range(1,13):
    x = self.cur.execute( """SELECT sum(kaxia) FROM es_data WHERE strftime('%m',es_date)= ? AND es_orig=1""",(str(i),) )
    m_totes_1=x.fetchone()[0]
    print q_totes_1
    if m_totes_1 is None:
        m_totes_1=0.0
```

You are also a victim of SQL Injection. (Always use `?` symbol in DBs)

[image]

Comment: Copied and pasted in my code. Still getting `operation parameter must be str or unicode`

Comment: So my code now looks like `self.cur.execute( """SELECT sum(kaxia) FROM es_data WHERE strftime('%m',es_date)= ? AND es_orig=1""",(str(i),) )
#            print q_totes_1
            m_totes_1=self.cur.fetchone()[0]
            print m_totes_1` but still `print m_totes_1` outputs `None`

Comment: Again the output is `None`. I know its something with the `strftime` because my initial code runs smoothly without it...

Comment: @Filippos you sure that it must return something? Or is there no data in the DB. I've checked the query and it works for me

Comment: If I run the query straight on sqlite I get the result `1000` which is what I expect. It seems that python won't ask the database or it won't ask it correctly. If I exclude the strftime portion I get (both through python and straight) `1200` which is also correct.

Comment: @Filippos Remove the `AND es_orig` part completely and check

Comment: Still result is `None`. It's driving me crazy!!! Again if I run the query straightly it gives me the correct answer (which of course isn't None).

Comment: Before `m_totes_1=x.fetchone()[0]` add `for i in x: print (i)` and reply with the results

Comment: So my code now looks like:    `for i in range(1,13):
            x = self.cur.execute( """SELECT sum(kaxia) FROM es_data WHERE strftime('%m',es_date)= ? AND es_orig=1""",(str(i),) )
            for i in x:
                print (i)
            m_totes_1=x.fetchone()[0]
            print m_totes_1
            if m_totes_1 is None:
                m_totes_1=0.0` and the result is `TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
(None,)`. Sorry formating in comments doesn't help